# Debugging blues

Tags: java, debugging

Help, I recieved the following errors for my code. I'm kinda new and I don't really understand why I'm getting these errors.

```
java 49: error : ')' expected

java 49: error : ';' expected

java 58: error: reached end of file while parsing
```

---

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class ProductDAO {
    private String filename;
    private ArrayList<Product> products;

    public ProductDAO(String filename) {    
        this.filename = filename;
        load();
    }

    private void load() {
        // TODO: update this method
        try {

            AppException a = new AppException("Cannot Load", FileNotFoundException);
            AppException b = new AppException("Invalid Number of Products");

            File f = new File(filename);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            Scanner scDl = sc.useDelimiter("\r\n");
            String listDes = scDl.nextLine();
            int numOfProducts = Integer.parseInt(listDes.substring(listDes.length()-1));

            String productList = scDl.nextLine();

            while (scDl.hasNextLine()) {
                productList = scDl.nextLine();
                ArrayList<String> prodDetail = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(productList.split(":")));
                String name = prodDetail.get(0);
                double price = Double.parseDouble(prodDetail.get(1));
                int quantity = Integer.parseInt(prodDetail.get(2));
                Product prod = null;
                if (prodDetail.get(3).equals("yes")) {
                    String expiryDate = prodDetail.get(4);
                    prod = new Food(name,price,quantity,expiryDate);
                } else {
                    prod = new Product(name,price,quantity);
                }
                products.add(prod);
            }

            if (products.size()!=numOfProducts) {
                throw b;
            }

        } catch (Exception a.getCause()) {
            a.getMessage();
        }

    }

    private void save() {
        // TODO: update this method
    }
}
```

Comment: Your exception handling is... very strange.  You declare `a` but never use it, declare exceptions at the very beginning for some reason (if you feel so strongly that the code is going to fail, that may be a sign of a problem to be fixed), your `catch` header has syntax I've never seen before, and in the `catch` block you don't actually do anything.

Comment: I'm suppose to throw a new exception object if filenotfoundexception is caught. If numOfProducts is more than product.size() I'm suppose to throw another exception object. How would you have handle it differently? I'm new at this and I'm not very sure myself

Comment: and i'm just suppose to print a message when a certain exception is caught

Comment: I wouldn't declare the exceptions at the start of the method.  Just declare it in-line when throwing one.  As for the `catch` block header, I guess look at some tutorials and examples of Java `catch` blocks.  `Exception a.getCause()` doesn't really make any sense, you're trying to declare a variable and execute a method at the same time.  You can differentiate the separate exceptions either by having separate `catch` blocks (which I'd probably prefer) or by examining the `Exception` object within the `catch` block.  And `getMessage()` returns a string, but you never print it anywhere.

Comment: Could you please show me an example for me to visualise. I'm still not very good in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrong exception catch block:

```
} catch (Exception a.getCause()) {
```

Should be:

```
} catch (Exception a) {
```

I.e. the exception class should be only followed by variable name that you'll later refer to.

Comment: Hi, after switching to your suggestion, I've encountered a new error on line 18: cannot find symbol:  AppException a = new AppException("Cannot Load", FileNotFoundException);
variable: FileNotFoundException
location: ProductDAO

Comment: @Clement: I'm pretty sure that constructor is expecting an object, not the name of a class.  `FileNotFoundException` is the name of a class.

Comment: @Clement : avoid that line completely, it obviously doesn't make any sense here.

Comment: Clement, one thing is to understand why you get the errors above -- which Saviour clearly helps out with -- and one other thing is to correct the whole of your code.
It is unethical to give downvotes to people trying to help because you don't know enough the language and solving issues generate new issues. That's your problem, not anyone else's. 
If you want to sole all of the problems with your code, stick it on an Eclipse or Intellij project and see the visual aids -- that'll be much faster.

Comment: the constructor for AppException is as followed
public AppException(String message, Throwable cause)
and
public AppException(String message)

Comment: @Clement: No, you don't have enough points to cast down-votes.  As for the `AppException` constructor, the second argument needs to be an *object*, not the name of a class.  You don't have any variables called `FileNotFoundException` (nor should you, as it would cause confusion with the name of the class).  Honestly, there is *a lot* wrong with this code.  You should probably start with something simpler and walk through some Java tutorials as you go along.